# MSSQL Transpose query results

Tags: sql-server

I've read various posts about PIVOT and UNPIVOT but I can't seem to wrap my head around the functions to  accomplish what I am after...  I have a query that groups data together and spits it out:

```
Machine      Date      Metric1     Metric2     Metric3     Metric4
------------------------------------------------------------------
machine 1    1/1/2014      1            2         3             4  
machine 1    1/2/2014      9            5         3             7 
machine 1    1/3/2014      1            1         1             1
```

But I am trying to have MSSQL give me the results like this:

```
Desc            1/1/2014      1/2/2014      1/3/2014
----------------------------------------------------
Metric 1          1           9                  1 
Metric 2          2           5                  1
Metric 3          3           3                  1
Metric 4          4           7                  1
```

I've tried the pivot and unpivot unsuccessfully.  Any tip on how to do this efficiently?  Everything I've tried so far in SQL Fiddle results in some data and some null fields.

Comment: Which various posts have you read? Please include links to them in your question to avoid users sending you links to things you've tried or closing this question as a duplicate, as this has been asked many times before.

Comment: In fact, this has been asked so many times that even the dreaded second page of Google still contains relevant search results.

Comment: Although the previous comments have a point, I have some questions: Are this the only dates you need? You'll have to know which values are present in advance or otherwise use Dynamic SQL. Where have your `Machines` gone in the results you provide?

Answer (score 2):

### Test_Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(Machine VARCHAR(100),[Date] Date, Metric1 INT, 
                        Metric2 INT, Metric3 INT, Metric4 INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('machine 1'   ,'1/1/2014'      ,1            ,2         ,3             ,4),  
('machine 1'   ,'1/2/2014'      ,9            ,5         ,3             ,7), 
('machine 1'   ,'1/3/2014'      ,1            ,1         ,1             ,1)
```

### Query

```
SELECT [Des], [2014-01-01],[2014-01-02],[2014-01-03]
FROM
(
SELECT Machine , [Date], Metric1 AS Metric, 'Metric1' AS [DES] FROM @TABLE 
UNION ALL
SELECT Machine , [Date], Metric2, 'Metric2' FROM @TABLE 
UNION ALL
SELECT Machine , [Date], Metric3, 'Metric3' FROM @TABLE 
UNION ALL
SELECT Machine , [Date], Metric4, 'Metric4' FROM @TABLE 
)t
PIVOT (SUM(Metric)
       FOR [Date]
       IN ([2014-01-01],[2014-01-02],[2014-01-03])
       )p
```

### Result Set

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║   Des   ║ 2014-01-01 ║ 2014-01-02 ║ 2014-01-03 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ Metric1 ║          1 ║          9 ║          1 ║
║ Metric2 ║          2 ║          5 ║          1 ║
║ Metric3 ║          3 ║          3 ║          1 ║
║ Metric4 ║          4 ║          7 ║          1 ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

Transpose = unpivot + pivot

```
SELECT Metric,[2014-01-01],[2014-01-02],[2014-01-03]
FROM MyTable
UNPIVOT(value FOR Metric IN (Metric1,Metric2,Metric3,Metric4)) t1
PIVOT(SUM(value) FOR Date IN ([2014-01-01],[2014-01-02],[2014-01-03])) t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your responses, as luck would have it I found the solution (as close as I can get) soon after asking.  For others who may have the same issue here's a SQL Fiddle of the end result.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6be41

Comment: The link you have posted does not contain the query - If the query that solved your problem is not in one of the other answers, please post it here to help others. if it is in the other answers consider accepting it as an answer.